# How to return a list from a recursive function for a factorial of a number in python?

Tags: python

for a given number x , I would like to return a list, that holds factorial of all the numbers up to that number in python
example : if n= 5, then I would like return  [ 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
if n= 5, then I would like return  [ 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]
my loop must be inside recursion function. basically I want a recursive function return a list ?

Comment: Have you written the recursive function? What problem are you having with your code?

Comment: Or is this a kind of assignment?

Comment: #to get the factorial of a number
def r6(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n == 1:
            return [1]
        return [ n * r6(n-1)]

x=r6(5)
print(x)

Comment: getting error unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: This is the code I ahve written

Comment: @Ramu consider editing the question with your code. It's hard to read in the comments since it can't be formatted properly.

Comment: #to get the factorial of a number
def r6(n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n == 1:
            return [1]
        return [ n * r6(n-1)]

x=r6(5)
print(x)

the error I got is unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 2):

With recursive functions you don't loop unless there's branching logic. You just start with the base case. Here, that's factorial(1) (or maybe zero). That should return a simple list without doing more recursions. Then the next one `fact(2)` will call `fact(1)` and append its new value. Then for `fact(n)` it will call `fact(n-1)`...

```
def fact(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return [1]    
    last = fact(n-1)
    return last + [n * last[-1]]

fact(6)
# [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]
```

Comment: thank you, what does last[-1] do  the above code?

Comment: @Ramu `last[-1]` is the last element in the returned list from the previous call. In other words it is the previous factorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaulted parameters to make the function shorter by passing counters down to the lower recursion levels:

```
def fact(n,k=2,f=1): return [f] + fact(n-1,k+1,k*f) if n else []

print(fact(5))
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Here, `n` is merely used as a descending counter to control the recursion depth, `k` is the next factor and `f` is the current factorial value to be added to the resulting list.